# Docker-compose ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED (Java Spring + Angular)

Tags: java, angular, docker, http, docker-compose

I have a two simple images:

```
#Angular image
FROM node:12.2.0

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9

COPY . /app

CMD ng serve
```

&

```
# Java spring (REST) image
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY ./target/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar", "app.jar"]
```

And my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web_app_speech:
    image: web_app_speech
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4300:4200"
    depends_on: 
      - api_speech_docker
  api_speech_docker:
    image: api_speech_docker
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
```

$> docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
15c719d31861        web_app_speech      "/bin/sh -c 'ng serv…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:4300->4200/tcp   azure_web_app_speech_1
044fd15f07e4        api_speech_docker   "java -Djava.securit…"   10 minutes ago      Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   azure_api_speech_docker_1
```

I can access my REST API from localhost:8080 and my web app from localhost:4300 without problem but when I try to perform a call from my web_app to my rest_api I have the following error:

```
OPTIONS http://api_speech_docker:8080/speech net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I have no idea how to fix this, if you need more logs tell me !

Thanks for your help

Comment: If the Web application is running in a browser, that has no idea the Docker host names exist.  You need to use your server’s host name and the published ports.

Comment: "Shell" into your web_app_speech container (docker exec -it ContainId sh) and try to ping the other container:   "ping api_speech_docker".  That should work.  However, you probably want to define a "network" in your compose file.

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi, thanks for you reply, can you be more precise please ? I need to change the url of my API call to something like 'localhost:8087' ?

Comment: @JoeG Hi, thanks for your reply. I can ping without problems my api from my web_app. I've defined a simple network (without configurations) before and it didn't worked.

Comment: Sorry, I should have suggested that if you can ping successfully from within the webapp container, then you should try to "curl" the http address from there (you may need to install curl in your container, you can do that from the command line, but may need to shell in with the -u0 switch) . Use curl -v .  and post the results

Comment: yes thank you, I called my API from localhost and everything works! Thank you

Comment: @thomasA please clear how you solved the problem.

Comment: @devloper152 did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No, I can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding your REST API is being called from your browser which cannot resolve the docker service names. For different applications, I used the following solutions:

**Use localhost:** `http://localhost:8080/speech`

- Works great for locally hosted projects
- If hosting on the cloud, may cause other errors

or

**Hit endpoint through public IP** `http://13.192.123.12:8080/speech`

- Only works if the IP address does not change
- If hosting on the cloud, inbound traffic through port 8080 must be allowed as well